# Zend Version Release Dates

Tags: zend-framework, documentation

Where can I find the release dates for each past release of the Zend Framework?

I'm constantly referring to blog articles and tutorials in my effort to learn the framework.  The articles are usually dated however without knowing the release dates of the framework, its difficult to marry up articles with their intended Zend version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need to watch for every single version
I think since 1.8 there are no significant changes that may affect the article so if it is from 2009 it should work.

Along with http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives you may also try to check http://framework.zend.com/changelog

Edit: brief history of major changes

1.0 first release - July 2007

1.5 Zend_Form, Zend_Layout - March 2008

**1.8 Zend_Application - April 2009, major difference in bootsraping**

1.9 Php 5.3 support - August 2009

1.10 ControllerTestCase - January 2010

1.11 Zend_Cloud - November 2010

Comment: They have changed the archives url a bit. Its http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives now.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the older releases (and their dates) of zend framework here:
[Edit]
[Zend](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives)